# Conditional distribution of a function of a random vector given conditional distribution of random vector

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, lognormal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,...,X_n)^T$ be a multivariate normal distribution. Now we have $\mathbf{Y}=(Y_1,...,Y_n)^T$ defined by $Y_i = e^{X_i}$. Let $\mathbf{Y^1}, \mathbf{Y^2}$ be partitions of $\mathbf{Y}$. I am interested in finding an expression for the conditional distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$:

$$f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y^2|y^1}) = \frac{{f_\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y^2,y^1})}{f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y^1})}.$$

I was able to derive the following relation between the joint distributions of $\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{X}$:

$$ f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{f_{\mathbf{X}}(ln\mathbf{y})}{y_1y_2...y_n}. $$

I am looking for some simple expression for the mean, variance, and distributions of the random variables in the partition $\mathbf{y^2}$ given knowledge of the random variables in partition $\mathbf{y^1}$. The conditional distribution expression is straight forward and elegant for the multivariate normal case but I am having a tough time trying to derive an expression for this random vector. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just solve the problem in the original $X$ coordinates and exponentiate.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would imply the same. The conditional distribution in $\mathbf{X}$ is another normal distribution. The exponential of that would be a lognormal distribution, but would it be equivalent to $f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{f_{\mathbf{X}}(ln\mathbf{y})}{y_1y_2...y_n}.$?

Comment: Because the transformations occur coordinate by coordinate, it doesn't matter whether you condition on the $X$'s or the $Y$'s.